# Strip or rewrite query string from cleaned url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, query-string, url-rewriting

What I'm looking to do is strip a query parameter from a dynamic URL that needs to also be cleaned using HTACCESS.

1. The url first starts as http://testdomain.com/post.php?id=3326.
2. The url is cleaned with a rewrite to http://testdomain.com/post/3326/.
3. Some links get **"?ref=no_set"** appended to the end
4. Url now needs to be redirected from http://testdomain.com/post/3326/?ref=no_set to http://testdomain.com/post/3326/

In some cases I need to add a new query parameter **"?ref=no_set"** to the url, but I'm wondering if it's possible to strip that query param and still be able to use $_GET in PHP to retrieve it even though it isn't being rewritten.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond [conditional reg ex here]

RewriteRule [rewrite reg ex here] - [CO=ref:no_set:.testdomain.com]
```

Comment: The current RewriteRule that I'm using is: RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]{1,11})/$ post.php?id=$1&ref=no_set [L,QSA]. 

I'm able to strip the query params from it using: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ref=
RewriteRule (.*) http://testdomain.com/$1? [R], but I'm unable to use $_GET when doing so...

Answer (score 0):

Simple...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule .* http://testdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L] 
# ADD CODE TO HANDLE YOUR REWRITES AFTER THIS
```

Have a nice day! ;)